# AFNetworking 2 downloading JPEG via POST straight into a File

Tags: post, download, jpeg, afnetworking-2

I am downloading jpeg images via POST request using AFNetworking 2.0:

---

```
[manager.httpManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"filename": imageName};
manager.httpManager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager.httpManager POST:URL_BASE_IMG parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Image: %@", responseObject);                

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

Showing the responseObject is not an issue. However, how can I specify a path so that the response object is downloaded straight into it? I have seen the use of streams but I do not know how to implement it here. Anybody? Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps I should be using AFURLSessionManager, however How can I use it with a POST request?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using GET when you are downloading images?

Comment: Not really. The images have copyright and we do not want them to be publicly available.

Comment: I ended up using afurlsessionmanager instead. Works like a champ so far

Comment: POST is for creating new resources.  GET is for getting resources.  You should be using GET.  You can authenticate requests, even with GET; they won't be publicly available.

Comment: @archipestre could pls tell me how to pass json parameter along with POST url using AFURLSessionManager